# how to use div as pages in apache cordova?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cordova, phonegap-cli

Thing I am trying to achieve is as follow

1. I want to create a single html page cordova app
2. My page will be single, but I want to show mutiple divs as pages.. (Only divs will be toggled as pages. I dont want to add another html page.)

Is it possible?
Please explain me...

following is structure which i wana achieve

```
<code>
<div class="main-content">
<div class="changing-content">
</div>
<div>
</code>
```

Comment: Why are you insisting on simulating multiple pages instead of just actually making multiple pages?

Comment: You can manage two type of format for creating phonegap app either Single Page App or Multiple Pages App, depends on your lengths of pages and javascript management.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a sample code for you, try and implement for yourself

```
<body>
    <div id="index">
        <div onclick="showPage('page1')">Page 1</div>
        <div onclick="showPage('page2')">Page 2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="page1" style="display:none">
        This is page1
        <div class="back" onclick="showPage('index')">Back</div>
    </div>
    <div id="page2" style="display:none">
        This is page2
        <div class="back" onclick="showPage('index')">Back</div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
var ids=['page1','page2','index'];
function showPage(pageId)
{
    for(i=0;i<ids.length;i++)
    {
        if(pageId == ids[i])
        {
            document.getElementById(pageId).style.display = "block";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(ids[i]).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/fp10tq4c/)

Comment: I think for PhoneGap many people who just judge the questions and answers instead of suggesting solutions. Go to ______, down voters !!!